Telebot выдает ошибку при отправке картинки
Пишу бота на python с помощью telebot, который получает информацию из Википедии с помощью библиотеки wikipedia и отправляет пользователю. В данном случае, у меня есть функция которая по отправленной теме от пользователя должна отправить картинку, но возникает ошибка:
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: IMAGE_PROCESS_FAILED . 
Как бы я не пытался не получается, можете подсказать что тут не так?
import requests
import telebot
import time
import os
from PIL import Image

<...>

@bot.message_handler(commands=['search_image']) 
def handle_search_image(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите тему по которой тебе нужно найти картинку.")

    def get_image(message):
        """
           Принимает тему от пользователя, находит соответствующую статью в Wikipedia
           и отправляет ссылку на первую найденную в ней картинку.
           """
        try:
            # Получаем страницу Wikipedia по заданной теме
            topic = message.text
            page = wikipedia.page(topic)
            image_url = page.images[0]

            # Загружаем изображение с URL-адреса
            response = requests.get(image_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0'})

            # Проверяем, что изображение загрузилось успешно
            if response.status_code == 200:
                # Сохраняем изображение на диск
                filename = f"{topic.replace(' ', '_')}.png"
                with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                    f.write(response.content)

                # Отправляем изображение в Telegram-бот
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибка при загрузке изображения.")
        except Exception as e:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
        finally:
            # Удаляем временный файл
            os.remove(filename)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_image)```


